# Bash: syntax error near unexpected token `else'

Tags: bash

I'm getting the following error:

```
./adduser.sh: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./adduser.sh: line 21: `        else'
```

I have been stuck here for an hour and I just can not figure it out.

```
#!/bin/bash
#==========================================================================================================================================
# Script Name:  adduser.sh
# By:           Tim mayo
# Date:         3/2013
# Purpose:      Add a user to the Linux system
# Command line: adduser.sh
#
#==========================================================================================================================================
        read -p "Enter username : " username
        read -s -p "Enter password : " password
        egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "$username exists!"
                exit 1
        else
                pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
                useradd -m -p $pass $username
                [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
        fi
                else
                        echo "Root user can only add a user to the Linux system"
                        exit 2
fi
```

Comment: can you put the whole script please, the identation suggests there are missing parts.

Answer (score 2):

The `else` keyword isn't associated with any `if` statement; you ended the `if` statement with the `fi` keyword on line 20. Perhaps you are missing an `if` just before the two `read` statements?

Comment: So simple thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to add   if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then ...before the read statements

Comment: @user2177712 Welcome to SO! If any answer worked for you, consider accepting it by clicking on hollow green tick mark on the left side of answer. *(below up-down votes)*

Answer (score 0):

Another 'run as root only' example:

```
   #!/bin/bash


if [ $UID -eq "0" ]
then
        read -p "Enter username : " username
        read -s -p "Enter password : " password
        egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "$username exists!"
                exit 1
        else
                pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
                useradd -m -p $pass $username
                [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
        fi
                 else
                        echo "Root user can only add a user to the Linux system"
                        exit 2
fi
```